# How to test a custom GitHub action without publishing it to marketplace?

Tags: github-actions

I created a GitHub action, I am looking for a way to test itself before publishing it to marketplace.
How can I test it by creating a workflow file within the same repository?

I have the following workflow.

```yaml
name: "Build"
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: test-action # name of my action
```

Comment: An action doesn't have to be published to the marketplace to be usable; marketplace just makes them discoverable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `./` syntax to use an action available in the same repository.

```yaml
  steps:  
    - uses: ./
      with:
       # input params if you have any
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also call the action specific branch to use an action which hasn't been published yet (**even in other repositories**).

```
  steps:  
    - uses: <username>/<repo-name>@<branch-name>
      with:
       # input params if there is any
```

This can (for example) allow to test implementations located in different branches.

Comment: You need to allow it in other repositories if it's private.
Under Access, choose Accessible from repositories in the 'ORGANIZATION NAME' organization. Reference: [Sharing actions and workflows from your private repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository).

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels of testing: system, integration, unit.

I am also an author of many Actions and I've described my approach in the [article](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/testing/1-testing-of-github-actions-intro/). The main idea is:

- You can use unit tests with familiar tools according the technology you use to test separate units of your action
- To test the whole action use [github-action-ts-run-api](https://github.com/cardinalby/github-action-ts-run-api) TS library to run tests both **locally** (to have short feedback loop without permanent pushes to the repo) and on CI (using your workflow).

The library emulates GitHub runner and has API to pass different inputs, env variables, analyse outputs, exit code, etc. of your action, supports executing JavaScript and Docker actions.