# How to test a github action in another repo without publishing?

Tags: github, github-actions

[How to test a custom GitHub action without publishing it to marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277818/how-to-test-a-custom-github-action-without-publishing-it-to-marketplace)

Similar question to ^ - I'm trying to test a GHA in a **different public** repository without publishing it.

This solution doesnt work for me

```
  steps:  
    - uses: <username>/<repo-name>@<branch-name>
      with:
       # input params if there is any
```

I get this error when running my GHA

```
line 1: <actualUserName>/<actual-repo-name>@main: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Do I need to provide a specific URL to the repo?

Comment: Did you try using the commit hash instead of the branch name? (the commit equivalent to the branch version) It should work as well on another repo.

Comment: Good call, I'll try that